# How to improve this email regex to support funny characters that are valid

Tags: ruby, regex

I have looked up many regex expressions online and after many tests they all fail to match this email:

`CAKyppebtX1Fe7t1bdZGABT1a9Pp4bp6zVnx=DA_69SwRpuBu4w@mail.gmail.com`

What I'm trying to do is extract emails from a block of text, and all i'm getting is the part after the `=` sign:

```
str    = 'Foo: <CAKyppebtX1Fe7t1bdZGABT1a9Pp4bp6zVnx=DA_69SwRpuBu4w@mail.gmail.com>'
emails = str.scan(/\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/i)

=> ['DA_69SwRpuBu4w@mail.gmail.com']
```

Comment: you do not include `=` sign in your group here `[A-Z0-9._%+-]`, just add it there.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can just add `=` to the regexp:

```
 str    = 'Foo: <CAKyppebtX1Fe7t1bdZGABT1a9Pp4bp6zVnx=DA_69SwRpuBu4w@mail.gmail.com>'
 emails = str.scan(/\b[A-Z0-9._%+-=]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/i)

 => ["CAKyppebtX1Fe7t1bdZGABT1a9Pp4bp6zVnx=DA_69SwRpuBu4w@mail.gmail.com"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Include `=` in the character class that you're using for the username?

```
str    = 'Foo: <CAKyppebtX1Fe7t1bdZGABT1a9Pp4bp6zVnx=DA_69SwRpuBu4w@mail.gmail.com>'
emails = str.scan(/\b[A-Z0-9._%+-=]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/i)

=> ["CAKyppebtX1Fe7t1bdZGABT1a9Pp4bp6zVnx=DA_69SwRpuBu4w@mail.gmail.com"]
```